# How to download reddit videos using Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can download videos by going to network panel in developer tools. But how do I do that with python +  selenium ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the url of where the file is hosted, and use `requests` to download and write it to a file. something like this

```
import requests

... <selnium code to parse web page>

def save_vid(name=None, url=None):
    if not name:
        name = 'video.mp4'

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
    response  = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})

    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        print ("Donloading chunck")
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=255): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    print("Done")
```

Update:

for reddit specifically, got the source of the video,

```
<video poster="https://external-preview.redd.it/lrJKPYDzKs2SYt2rc0ig4hipMuD4JNPn24fjrV3NMLQ.png?width=960&amp;crop=smart&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=44e72857f61ea62d7a447a9246961aeb3ae0322d" muted="" preload="auto" class="HTML5StreamPlayer__video__regular" src="blob:https://www.reddit.com/dbfa2e9f-07da-4bc3-b258-d12ba9c4ca67">
 --> <source src="https://v.redd.it/l67upl0tug921/HLSPlaylist.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegURL">
</video>
```

get the video ID

from `src="https://v.redd.it/l67upl0tug921/HLSPlaylist.m3u8`, 
ID = `l67upl0tug921`

hosted video `https://v.redd.it/l67upl0tug921/DASH_4_8_M`

Use function above to download.

> Note: make sure to use a user-agent in request + 1 second delay for bots (according to reddit)

Comment: It uses a blob file and gets its video file with ajax request. Not easy to get a absolute url.

Comment: If you add more info on the site. maybe the url or screenshots or something, I can be more help.  You may still be able to get the full url